# need a shell script to log datastream from bluetooth (+visualising?)

Tags: macos, shell, logging, bluetooth

Let's suppose, I have some device `/dev/btooth` or something like that which outputs a stream consisting of four bytes separated by some certain marker (let's suppose it is a sequence 0,255,13) with a speed of 10 quadruples a second. 
I need to log this stream to a file of lines. What I don't want to do is to log write to files so often (I'm afraid my SSD won't survive). 
So, the stream is like:

```
25,64,0,255,13,10,3,0,15,0,255,13,53,65,254,252,0,255,13,...
```

the file should look like

```
10,0,0,15
53,65,254,252
```

---

Drawing live plots would be even better, though I'm not sure it's possible in shell. 
There might be some other solutions (logging+visualising on Mac OS X?)